# Strange inequalities for this lightbulbs probability problem?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, moment-generating-functions

I am struggling to wrap my head around parts of this problem and would love any help!

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ (and $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$) and $X$ be i.i.d. r.v.s with MGF $M_X(t)$.

i) Show that for $t\geq0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{P}(S_n\geq nx)\leq\text{e}^{-nxt+n\log M_X(t)}$

Thoughts so far: this looked to me like Markov's inequality, so $\mathbb{P}(S_n\geq nx)\leq\frac{\mathbb{E}(S_n)}{nx}$, and furthermore $M_{S_n}(t)=M_X(t)^n$ since they are i.i.d. My next intention was to use the fact that $\text{d}M_{S_n}/\text{d}t\Big|_{t=0}$ was the expected value of $S_n$, but I'm not sure if I can implicitly claim that the expectation and derivative operators commute.

ii) Show also that this inequality remains valid for $t<0$, provided $x\geq\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Thoughts so far: I'm not sure how the $t<0$ comes into play, but my gut tells me we are looking for a stronger inequality, and $x\geq\mathbb{E}(X)$ hints at Chebyshev, but like before I have trouble dealing with the RHS.

iii) Deduce that, for $x\geq\mathbb{E}(X)$,
$$\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac1n\log \mathbb{P}(S_n\geq nx)\leq-I_X(x),$$
where $I_X(x)=\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\{xt-\log M_X(t)\}$. I have no idea where this comes from. The only inequality I know involving some form of lim inf/sup is Fatou's lemma, but I don't see how that applies here. Additionally, how does one not only interpret $I_X(x)$? I don't have much intuition for this variable.

iv) Let $I_\lambda(x)$ represent $I_X(x)$ when $X\sim\text{Expo}(\lambda)$ and $I_p(x)$ represent $I_X(x)$ when $X\sim\text{Bern}(p)$. When fitting a light bulb, the probability that it fails instantaneously is $1-p$; if it does not, its lifetime $T\sim \text{Expo}(\lambda)$. Let $p_n(x)$ denote the probability that the average lifetime of $n$ bulbs exceeds $x$ (>$1/\lambda$). I need to show that $p_n\leq\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-NI_\lambda(\frac{nx}{N})\right)\right]$, where $N\sim\text{Binom}(n,p)$. I also need to show that 
$$\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac1n\log p_n(x)\leq-\inf_{y\in[0,1]}\{I_p(y)+yI_\lambda(x/y)\}.$$
I have seen a derivation of $p_n(x)$ in the conditional probability section of Blitzstein and Hwang's textbook so I think reaching the inequality should be ok using part i) once I wrap my head around the meaning of $I_\lambda$, but once again my question for this part is the interpretation of the RHS of the inequality - my gut tells me the infimum is a result of the failing condition, but this is still not helping me understand much.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/545697), a reference found using the efficient "formula tracker" tool https://approach0.xyz/

Comment: as far as the interpretation of $I_X(X)$ it helps to have some familiarity with the **Legendre Transform** as that is essentially what is being used.  As is I can't tell what the focus of the question is.  What do you want out of this question? e.g. "$\text{d}M_{S_n}/\text{d}t\Big|_{t=0}$ *was the expected value of , but I'm not sure if I can implicitly claim that the expectation and derivative operators commute"* this comes down to an analytic fact about MGFs that's searchable on this site, and outside the scope of your question IMO.  'de-kitchen sinking' this will make it more tractable.

Comment: @user8675309 hi, could you talk a bit more about the legendre transform for this case?